# How to reset a specific order by column?

Tags: product-collection, sorting, select, sort

I have a product collection that use a `addAttributeToSort`.

Now there exists a sort filter in the frontend to sort products e.g. for **price or date.**

When I click that filter in the frontend I have to reset my first order by.
But now the problem is I can only reset the order after the frontend runs his new order.

So my question is there a possibility to reset only specific order by columns or can I only reset all order at once?

Answer (score 13):

The available sorting methods are

```
addOrder(), setOrder(), unshiftOrder(), addAttributeToSort() and getSelect()->order()
```

Only `setOrder($field, $dir)` is available regardless of collection type and system settings. I suggest you get used to using `setOrder()`.

If you need to enforce an order, but an order is already set on the collection, use `unshiftOrder($field`, `$dir)` for flat table collections.

For EAV collections you need to do

```
$col->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER); And then use $col->setOrder($field, $dir);
```

Resource: http://tweetorials.tumblr.com/post/11137227678/magento-collection-ordering-or-sorting

Comment: I needed to write this: $collection->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::ORDER)->order(['created desc']);